# small c compiler for educational purpose

Tags: c, compiler-construction, xv6

Is there any small c compiler which follows ansi c extensions and still it has less than 10,000 LOC. Basically 'm trying to port such small compiler to one of such educational OS kernel known as xv6. Thanks.

Comment: Never quite understand the concept of teaching somebody something that they will never use in the real world

Comment: If you have an assembler and a linker running within xv6 (or if you can port NASM or implement a very small subset of it on xv6), porting my [SmallerC](https://github.com/alexfru/SmallerC) should be fairly easy. There have been many improvements recently and now the compiler is self-hosing on DOS, Windows and Linux and can cross-compile to these 3 platforms. It also has most of the standard library implemented (except those functions that require unsupported language features (e.g. floating point, passing/returning structures by value, full preprocessor)).

Comment: So, while [Smaller C](https://github.com/alexfru/SmallerC) still depends on NASM (or YASM) to compile the assembly code generated from C code, it can now use FASM with a simple wrapper (see n2f.c in Smaller C) to translate NASM syntax to FASM syntax and layout. And FASM is written in itself. Which means porting Smaller C and FASM should now be easy, just teach FASM and the Smaller C library to use xv6 system calls and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's possible. You might try something like https://github.com/alexfru/SmallerC , a very small compiler for a subset of C. (See the wiki for the language)

Or look at pcc, but that is significantly larger.

Comment: Right now Smaller C is at about 8-9KLOC. I'm hoping to add support for structures soon, which will add some more lines. But one also needs an assembler and a linker (I'm not sure xv6 comes with its own). Those alone will make it larger than 10KLOC. And if you throw in a decent preprocessor... We're looking at ~15KLOC, give or take. And that's for a subset of ANSI C.

Comment: Basic support for struct and union has just been added. At ~10 KLOC now.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out xv6 badly needs several improvements in order to host a decent C compiler or just an assembler and a linker:

- larger maximum file size (currently capped at around 64KB)
- lseek
- FPU state saving/restoring on context switches

A few other minor improvements may be needed.

Links:

- [Increasing the filesystem block size in the xv6 OS](http://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=30594)
- [system calls & toolchains](http://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=30602)

Answer (score 0):

The smallest one I know is TCC http://bellard.org/tcc/ which has around 30 000 LOC.

Comment: xv6 in itself is 10K LOC. :)

Comment: @erbdex It's hard to beat 10 KLOC, unless it's an entry for ioccc.org. :) I've just added support for struct and union in Smaller C and the code is at ~10 KLOC (still lacking enum, typdef, floating point, some bits here and there, normal preprocessor and its own assembler and linker).