# small PHP runtime (interpreter) for educational purpose

Tags: php, interpreter

Is there any small PHP runtime (interpreter) for learning PHP? I think creating my own PHP runtime is a good way to understand how PHP works.

It seems that C language has some toy compilers for learning but I could not find it for PHP.

I prefer the following condition:

- written in C language
- compatible x86-64 architecture (Linux)

[small c compiler for educational purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20267092/small-c-compiler-for-educational-purpose)

---

Update 1

I'm looking for PHP toy compilers for learning the programming language like TCC: Tiny C Compiler. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler

---

Update 2

[This site](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-php-executes-from-source-code-to-render/) shows that PHP has the following execution processes.

```
1 Lexing
2 Parsing
3 Compilation
4 Interpretation
```

I want to understand the all processes. I need to read the [official interpreter](https://github.com/php/php-src) but it seems be difficult for me. So I want to start with smaller one.

Comment: PHP is written in C so most compilers will work. But I strongly suspect this is not the question you're really asking.

Comment: PHP does not get compiled, so looking _for_ a compiler makes rather little sense to begin with, IMHO. Either use `php` on the command line, or set up your own web server with PHP. If that doesn’t suit your needs - then you need to describe those a bit better to begin with.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your comment. I want to learn the PHP execution process. The following shows PHP has the four processes.
1 Lexing, 2 Parsing, 3 Compilation, 4 Interpretation. I want to know about the each process. https://www.sitepoint.com/how-php-executes-from-source-code-to-render/

Comment: @04FS PHP itself is compiled. The thing you are compiling is capable of interpreting PHP code. OP is asking about (his possible own) compiler that produces that binary that is capable of interpreting php code.

Comment: @Xatenev _“produces that binary that is capable of interpreting php code”_ - but the php executable already exists …

Comment: That very same article you linked to already explains ways to get more detailed info about what happens in the lexing, parsing and compiling stage. I don’t think there is any more compact way to get what you are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, it's called PH7: https://ph7.symisc.net/

This is a single file embeddable PHP interpreter compatible with approximately 5.3 with some enhancements.

Note however that it does not implement the majority of the PHP standard library.

Answer (score 2):

Again this may not be what you're looking for;

But I always found installing a mock apache server with PHP was the easiest way to learn PHP (and practise building within an environment in which PHP is most commonly used)

A simple IDE (Notepad ++) and XAMPP (or WAMP) set up will have a local server with the easy ability to use PHP.

XAMPP: https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html
WAMP: http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Notepad++: https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/

Like I say; this may not be what you're after...

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I'm looking for PHP toy compilers for learning programming language like TCC: Tiny C Compiler. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild PHP5/7 with:

1. Maximum number of the extensions disabled.
2. With optimization (for size) flag on.
3. Make sure the binary is stripped.

This will technically reduce the size of the interpreter and the number of extensions installed.

You should be able to provide these options during "./configure" step , see "./configure --help" for more information about it.